# How to get VS2008 to create a different *.DLL name after you have already created the project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

To create a project in VS2008 you have to assign the compiled output a name right when you create the project.  If you are creating a class library this output is <output name>.DLL.  I can change every other name in the project through the VS2008 interface.  If I later regret the output's name I cannot find a way to change the project's output *.exe or *.dll name.

How does one change the name of the *output* of a VS2008 project when the project has been created and that output name has been already defined?

Comment: My colleague pointed out that the answer is in VS2008 to open the 'Solution Explorer', then 'Right click project name' and select 'properties.'  On the popup window that appears look to the left and select the 'Application' tab.  Change the text in the field labeled 'Assembly Name' to the desired output filename.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the assembly name in the project properties.

In Solution Explorer, find the project you're interested in and double click on "Properties" (just under the project name). That will bring up the properties page for the project in the main editor view.

In the "Application" tab there's an "Assembly name" option - this is what decides the output filename.

Comment: Note: this is a bit different if you have a C++ project (and Class Library is a C++ option!).

Answer (score 5):

For C++ I found this option under Linker->General->Output File

Answer (score 1):

In the Project Properties, on the Application tab, just change the "Assembly name" property.

Answer (score 1):

The the project properties, under the "Application" tab, the field "Assembly name" will change the name for the output exe or dll.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the project, hit properties, there's an input on the Application tab called 'Assembly Name', that's your dll name.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2008 I fixed this by opening the <project name>.csproj and editing the text that appears between the <Assembly Name> .. and .. </Assembly Name> XML tags to be the desired output assembly file name.

EDIT: I posted the question so that I could share my answer with everyone.  I am truly impressed by the speed of the answers I got.  Thank you.

@John Saunders - I come from a UNIX background so when the UI doesn't yield an answer after a few minutes of poking I tend to go spelunking with 'emacs' or 'vi.'

Comment: Yes, you can do it the hard way too ;)

Comment: What was your reason for doing this by editing the project file? Did you need to do it for more than one project?

Comment: Honestly, I come from a Unix background and when the UI is not immmediately helpful I tend to go spelunking in the files with 'emacs' or 'vi.'