# change the name of output dll

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-1.1

I am working on .net 1.1  legacy system and need to change the name of outputted dll.

When I go to change the "output file" under project property it's greyed out and won't let me change it.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get VS2008 to create a different \*.DLL name after you have already created the project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007034/how-to-get-vs2008-to-create-a-different-dll-name-after-you-have-already-create)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Depending on which version of Visual Studio.NET you are running, try going to Project Properties -> Application, and then change the `Assembly Name` field. On earlier versions it might be in a different place but I think the `Assembly Name` field is still the one you are looking for.

Comment: For .NET Core you can add `<AssemblyName>my-new-name</AssemblyName>` to the **.csproj** file.

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio 2017, change the "Target Name" under Project Properties-> Configuration Properties-> General.

Answer (score 3):

In a C++ dll project using VS 2019 the option can be found in Project > Properties > Linker > General > Output File. Found answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5356549/1582588).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when I refactored a project and my DB project reference kept reverting back to the original naming scheme and outputting the reference in my bin folder. The solution for me was to open the DB projects properties => click on the SQLCLR tab => and then update both the Assembly Name and Default Namespace. Hope this helps.